# Center tap vs diode bridge rectifier in Multisim

Tags: rectifier, full-bridge

I made a full wave circuit in Multisim using a center tap.  The result I got confuses me. I am expecting a full wave rectified sinewave but I keep getting a square wave. Also, the voltage in the resistor is not within my calculations.

[image]

When I made this diode bridge, everything is within my expectation. I used the formula 2Vm/Pi and the voltage in the resistor is correct.

[image]

Can someone please explain what went wrong with my center tap circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can someone please explain it to me, what went wrong with my center
> tap circuit?*

In the centre-tapped bridge circuit, the peak reverse voltage seen by the rectifier diodes is up to twice the magnitude of a regular single winding bridge rectifier. Given that you have chosen a 1N5400 (rated at 50 volts repetitive peak reverse voltage), I expect that they are starting to heavily conduct when reverse biased. This will clip the rectified signal as you have shown.

Try using a 1N5401 (100 volts rated).